# Handling redirect to a specific page

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, deadbolt

I'm using [Deadbolt](http://deadbolt-2-java.herokuapp.com) for authorization. I need to redirect an user if he is present (`subjectPresent`). For example, this controller renders the signup page:

```
public static Result signup() {
     return ok(signup.render())
 }
```

But if a user is already present (then he's already registered) the above controller has to redirect him to his profile page: `return ok(profilePage.render())`

How can do it with annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deadbolt isn't really for this kind of conditional switching, but you could hack it in the following way:

1. Create another DeadboltHandler, called something like SubjectPresentHandler
2. Implement the SubjectPresentHandler#onAuthFailure method to redirect to the profile page
3. Annotate your signup method with

   @SubjectNotPresent(handler=SubjectPresentHandler.class)

This causes an authorisation failure if a user is present.  This will then invoke SubjectPresentHandler#onAuthFailure to obtain the result.

However, personally I would consider adding a simple test within the signup method along the lines of

```
public static Result signup() {
    Result result;
    User user = // however you normally get your user
    if (user == null) {
        result = ok(signup.render())
    } else {
        result = redirect(routes.<your profile view method>);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your answer (and for your plugin). Could you take a look also to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978971/deadbolt-show-parts-of-template-only-for-current-logged-user)? thanks